# Laravel update database with value from option

Tags: database, laravel

I'm trying to update a value inside of my database from a user selected option list.

my front-end:

```
<!-- Modal Edit MAANDpicker-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editMaandModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editMaandModal"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Wijzig maand</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('maandmenuMaandUpdate') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf


                    <label>Selecteer maand</label>
                    <select name="category_id" id="cat_id">

                    @php
                        $month = array("Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December");
                        foreach($month as $maand){
                        echo "<option value='1' id='$maand'>$maand</option>";
                        }
                    @endphp

                    </select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn cancel-button" data-dismiss="modal">Sluit</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn plus-button-modal">Wijzig maand</button>
            </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Web.php

```
 Route::post('/maandmenu/updateMaand','MaandmenuController@updateMaand')->name('maandmenuMaandUpdate');
```

The function in my controller is:

```
public function updateMaand(Request $request)
{
    $category = maandPicker::findOrFail($request->category_id);

    $category->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->back()->with('alert-success', 'Maand succesvol gewijzigd.');

}
```

Table schema:

```
Schema::create('maand_pickers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

But somehow I can't update my database even though the page doesn't give me any errors back. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

SOLUTION:

```
                        <label>Selecteer maand</label>
                    @php
                    $months = array("Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December");
                    @endphp

                    @foreach ($maandPicker as $maand)             
                    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="{{ $maand->id }}">
                    <select name="month">
                    @endforeach
                    @foreach ($months as $month)
                        <option value="{{ $month }}">{{ $month }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using `value=1` for all items in your select.
You can replace you select by the following and it will work:

```
@php
$months = array("Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December");
@endphp

<input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="{{ $maandPicker->id }}">
<select name="month">
@foreach ($months as $month)
    <option value="{{ $month }}">{{ $month }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

and then to process your update:

```
public function updateMaand(Request $request)
{
    $category = maandPicker::findOrFail($request->category_id);
    $category->name = $request->month;
    $category->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('alert-success', 'Maand succesvol gewijzigd.');
}
```

On a side note, I would avoid using `@php` in your blade templates and send the data directly from the controller instead.

Comment: Thanks, this way my code does indeed look cleaner. However, when I submit it, the pages goes to a 404 page and the database cell is still not updated. I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong for this issue to be fixed

Comment: It is redirecting to which URL? And can you share your table shema?

Comment: Yeah it will redirect towards route I added in my initial post here. It should go towards the 'updateMaand' function in my controller. I also added my table schema!

Comment: You are getting a 404 because of your `findOrFail()` since the id doesn't exist it will 'fail' and return 404. for example, if you select `Januari` it will try `maandPicker::findOrFail(0);` since the `$key` is 0 in your array

Comment: That's why I had the 'value="1"' before so it wouldn't give me the 404 back, but even then it wouldn't update my value inside the database. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: can you share the controller function that returns the blade view that you are showing?

Comment: Now, regarding your update function, I don't really understand your logic. you are searching a category in the `maand_pickers` table - is that what you are trying to achieve? can you share the `categories` schema as well?

Comment: In my database, I have in "maand_pickers" table the id "1" and name "Maart" , in the front -end I have the option list with the 12 months from the array. I want to be able to choose one, and then the one in the database will update to the selected one.

Comment: Can you try to provide an example of update you are trying to achieve: (table row before update -> Table row after update)

Comment: Table row before update. [id = 1] [name = Maart] , and for example, the user chooses Januari, then I want the table row after the update to be [id=1] [name = Januari]

Comment: please try my updated answer, I'm not sure where you get category_id from so I assumed `$category->id`

Comment: Thanks, I added your answer and had to change the $category->id into $maandPicker->id and then it worked!

Comment: Awesome! glad to be of any help 